# Get a custom attribute from a property with strong typing

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I have a class `Foo` with a property `Bar` that has a custom attribute I'd like to retrieve.

```
public class Foo {
  [ThisAttribute("The string I want to get")]
  public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I could get the attribute value like so

```
var name = typeof(Foo).GetProperty("Bar").GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ThisAttribute)).PropertyName;
```

However, if the property were renamed, this would break. Is there a way to retrieve the attribute without hardcoding the string name of the property, and, rather, reference the specific property directly?

Comment: You can use `nameof(Foo.Bar)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is use [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof):

```
var name = typeof(Foo)
    .GetProperty(nameof(Foo.Bar))
    .GetCustomAttribute<ThisAttribute>()
    .PropertyName;
```

Then if you rename `Bar`, it will cause a compilation error.

Obviously it doesn't enforce a property of `Foo` to be used, so could still cause a runtime exception, but it's safer than using a string for the above reason.

Note that `GetCustomAttribute` also has a generic overload.